# Operator overloading in Javascript

Tags: javascript, syntax

I'm trying to port this Javascript function (shortened for clarity):

```
Vertices.scale = function(vertices, scaleX, scaleY, point) {

    point = point || Vertices.centre(vertices);

};
```

`point` is a vector, i.e. an object of the form `{ x: 5, y: 10 }`. `Vertices.centre(vertices)` returns a similar vector object.

As far as I can see, there is no overloading of the '||' operator in the source code. In fact, I don't think you can overload operators in Javascript.

What does this code mean in plain English then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the same as:

```
Vertices.scale = function(vertices, scaleX, scaleY, point) {
    if (point) {
        point = point;
    } else {
        point = Vertices.centre(vertices);
    }
}
```

Convention using `||` (logical OR operator) is shorthand for using default values for function paramters. (but notice that it won't work for `boolean` parameters).

You can find more about logical operators on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR_())

Comment: It seems so. In javascript you can call function with any number of parameters.

Comment: Thank you madox2. Very different than the language I'm trying to port this framework too :)